# How to stop UITableView Cells from disappearing on view change

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have encountered a strange bug when changing a Container View's view using `addSubView` the contents of the UITableView disappear.

This UITableView is dynamic and I'm setting the cells from an array. At the moment the contents of the array aren't being used, it's just counting the length of the array and generating that number of cells.

As you can see from the [start of this video](http://youtu.be/jiBeaa8_1Tw) that the the table view loads fine on first view. But then when I change the contents of the container view to another view and then back again the cells seem to load, and then disappear!

I'm using a custom Segue to change the views on the menu button clicks using the following code

```
-(void) perform {
    HomeViewController *src = (HomeViewController *)[self sourceViewController];
    UIViewController *dst = (UIViewController *)[self destinationViewController];

    //Clear view of all subviews
    for (UIView *view in src.placeholderView.subviews) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
    //save destination
    src.currentViewController = dst;

    //set placeholderOutlet to destination
    [src.placeholderView addSubview:dst.view];
 }
```

The code within the UITableViewController is as follows.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;


    NSMutableArray *thisBlocks = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:7];

    Blocks *block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"232323";
    block.Name = @"128 Some Road";

    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"140332";
    block.Name = @"12 Another Road";
    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"889752";
    block.Name = @"Quadrant Square";
    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"1403323";
    block.Name = @"12 Some Road";
    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"8897522";
    block.Name = @"Quadrant Square";
    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"1403392";
    block.Name = @"12 Another Road";
    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    block = [[Blocks alloc] init];
    block.ID = @"8897520";
    block.Name = @"Quadrant Square";
    [thisBlocks addObject:block];

    self.blocks = thisBlocks;

    //NSLog(@"array: %@", self.blocks);

    //NSLog(@"Rows : %lu", (unsigned long)[self.blocks count] );
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    // Return the number of rows in the section.

    return [self.blocks count];
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"BlockCell"];


    return cell;
}
```

This has really got me stumped. Any ideas?

Comment: Is you table view controller being deallocated (implement dealloc and put a log in it to see if it's being called)?

Comment: Just a guess: Is your "perform" method executed, when you return to the tableview? So that the tableview will be loaded, filled and then "perform" destroys all your hard work with the fast enumeration through it's subview ([view removeFromSuperview];) so that the tableview will be removed?

Comment: I think rdelmar had it. I had my ViewController set a `(weak, nonatomic)`. Changing it to `(strong, nonatomic) fixed the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

rdelmar had it. I had my ViewController set a (weak, nonatomic). Changing it to `(strong, nonatomic) fixed the issue. Thanks –  Glenn Flanagan 43 secs ago   edit